# Asterisk call recording not showing any logs and file

Tags: asterisk, audio-recording, sip-server

I am trying to record calls using Asterisk (Version 11.7.0.5) but it is not working. I have done the following steps but no logs are visible on console (Debug and verbose level 5)

1. Added goip and users in sip.conf
2. Using MixMonitor to record calls
3. Changing permission of /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/

My sip.conf config is

```
[IMSI4051XXXXXXXXXXXX]
callerid=21005
username=user3
canreinvite=no
type=friend
context=sip-external
host=dynamic
dtmfmode=info
allow=all
directmedia=yes

    ; GOIP

[goip]
type=friend
username=goip
fromuser=goip
regexten=goip                                        ; When they register, create extension 401
secret=goip                                          ; Asterisk extension password
context=goip_context
dtmfmode=inband                                      ; Very important for DISA to work
call-limit=1                                         ; Limit to 1 call max
callerid=101
host=dynamic
nat=no                                               ; Gateway is not behind a NAT router
canreinvite=no                                       ; Typically set to NO if behind NAT
insecure=very
qualify=yes
allow=all
directmedia=yes
```

And extensions.conf is

```
[macro-dialGSM]
exten=>s,1,Dial(SIP/${ARG1},20,M(record))
exten=>s,2,Goto(s-${DIALSTATUS},1})
exten=>s-CANCEL,1,Hangup
exten=>s-NOANSWER,1,Hangup
exten=>s-BUSY,1,Busy(30)
exten=>s-CONGESTION,1,Congestion(30)
exten=>s-CHANUNAVAIL,1,playback(ss-noservice)
exten=>s-CANCEL,1,Hangup

[goip_context]
exten=>_93.,1,Macro(dialGSM,goip@192.168.10.6:5062)

[macro-record]
exten=>s,1,MixMonitor(testrecording.wav)
```

The logs are as under.

```
Asterisk Ready.
  == Using SIP RTP TOS bits 184
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [93278388855@from-openBTS:1] Set("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "CDR(B-Number)=93278388855") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@from-openBTS:2] Set("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "CDR(A-IMSI)=IMSI405140603684903") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@from-openBTS:3] Set("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "CDR(A-Name)=") in new stack
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.375] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:191 generic_execute: SQL Execute returned an error -1: HY000: [SQLite]unable to open database file (14) (41)
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.375] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:199 generic_execute: SQL Exec Direct failed (-1)![select callerid from sip_buddies where username="IMSI405140603684903"]
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.375] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: res_odbc.c:608 ast_odbc_direct_execute: SQL Execute error! Verifying connection to asterisk [asterisk]...
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.375] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:191 generic_execute: SQL Execute returned an error -1: HY000: [SQLite]unable to open database file (14) (41)
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.375] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:199 generic_execute: SQL Exec Direct failed (-1)![select callerid from sip_buddies where username="IMSI405140603684903"]
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.375] ERROR[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:538 acf_odbc_read: Unable to execute query [select callerid from sip_buddies where username="IMSI405140603684903"]
    -- Executing [93278388855@from-openBTS:4] Set("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "CDR(A-Number)=") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@from-openBTS:5] ExecIf("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "1?Set(CDR(A-Number)=IMSI405140603684903):Set(CALLERID(num)=)") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@from-openBTS:6] GotoIf("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "0?emergency,911,1") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@from-openBTS:7] GotoIf("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "0?default,93278388855,1") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@from-openBTS:8] Goto("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "phones,93278388855,1") in new stack
    -- Goto (phones,93278388855,1)
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.376] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:191 generic_execute: SQL Execute returned an error -1: HY000: [SQLite]unable to open database file (14) (41)
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.376] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:199 generic_execute: SQL Exec Direct failed (-1)![select dial from dialdata_table where exten="93278388855"]
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.376] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: res_odbc.c:608 ast_odbc_direct_execute: SQL Execute error! Verifying connection to asterisk [asterisk]...
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.376] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:191 generic_execute: SQL Execute returned an error -1: HY000: [SQLite]unable to open database file (14) (41)
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.376] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:199 generic_execute: SQL Exec Direct failed (-1)![select dial from dialdata_table where exten="93278388855"]
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.376] ERROR[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:538 acf_odbc_read: Unable to execute query [select dial from dialdata_table where exten="93278388855"]
    -- Executing [93278388855@phones:1] Set("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "CDR(B-IMSI)=") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@phones:2] GotoIf("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "0?B-IPAddr") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@phones:3] Gosub("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "to-e164,93278388855,1") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@to-e164:1] Return("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "93278388855") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@phones:4] Set("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "CDR(B-Number)=93278388855") in new stack
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.377] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:191 generic_execute: SQL Execute returned an error -1: HY000: [SQLite]unable to open database file (14) (41)
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.377] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:199 generic_execute: SQL Exec Direct failed (-1)![select dial from dialdata_table where exten="93278388855"]
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.377] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: res_odbc.c:608 ast_odbc_direct_execute: SQL Execute error! Verifying connection to asterisk [asterisk]...
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.377] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:191 generic_execute: SQL Execute returned an error -1: HY000: [SQLite]unable to open database file (14) (41)
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.377] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:199 generic_execute: SQL Exec Direct failed (-1)![select dial from dialdata_table where exten="93278388855"]
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.377] ERROR[1505][C-00000000]: func_odbc.c:538 acf_odbc_read: Unable to execute query [select dial from dialdata_table where exten="93278388855"]
    -- Executing [93278388855@phones:5] Set("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "CDR(B-IMSI)=") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@phones:6] GotoIf("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "1?to-pstn,93278388855,1") in new stack
    -- Goto (to-pstn,93278388855,1)
    -- Executing [93278388855@to-pstn:1] Set("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "CDR(hangupdirection)=A") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@to-pstn:2] Gosub("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "CallLimit,s,1(IMSI405140603684903,93278388855)") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@CallLimit:1] GotoIf("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "1?A-IMSI") in new stack
    -- Goto (CallLimit,s,4)
    -- Executing [s@CallLimit:4] ExecIf("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "0?Return()") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@CallLimit:5] Set("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "GROUP(A)=IMSI405140603684903") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@CallLimit:6] GotoIf("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "0?VM") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@CallLimit:7] Return("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@to-pstn:3] Dial("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "SIP/93278388855@,3600,g") in new stack
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.379] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: chan_sip.c:6160 create_addr: Purely numeric hostname (), and not a peer--rejecting!
[2017-02-15 09:51:09.379] WARNING[1505][C-00000000]: app_dial.c:2437 dial_exec_full: Unable to create channel of type 'SIP' (cause 20 - Subscriber absent)
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
    -- Executing [93278388855@to-pstn:4] Set("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "CDR(hangupdirection)=SYSTEM") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@to-pstn:5] GotoIf("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "1?:h-20,1") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@to-pstn:6] Dial("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "SIP/93278388855@goip,3600,g") in new stack
  == Using SIP RTP TOS bits 184
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Called SIP/93278388855@goip
    -- SIP/goip-00000001 is ringing
    -- SIP/goip-00000001 is making progress passing it to SIP/00101100010-00000000
       > 0x7f216001f550 -- Probation passed - setting RTP source address to 192.168.10.6:16384
    -- SIP/goip-00000001 answered SIP/00101100010-00000000
       > 0x7f2178014760 -- Probation passed - setting RTP source address to 127.0.0.1:16562
       > Saved useragent "dble" for peer goip
    -- Executing [93278388855@to-pstn:7] Set("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "CDR(hangupdirection)=B") in new stack
    -- Executing [93278388855@to-pstn:8] Goto("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "h-16,1") in new stack
    -- Goto (to-pstn,h-16,1)
    -- Executing [h-16@to-pstn:1] Progress("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [h-16@to-pstn:2] NoOp("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "AST_CAUSE_NORMAL_CLEARING,noanswer") in new stack
    -- Executing [h-16@to-pstn:3] Hangup("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "16") in new stack
  == Spawn extension (to-pstn, h-16, 3) exited non-zero on 'SIP/00101100010-00000000'
    -- Executing [h@to-pstn:1] Log("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "NOTICE,A-Number=IMSI405140603684903 A-Name= A-IMSI=IMSI405140603684903 B-Number=93278388855 B-Name= B-IMSI= hangupcause=16 dialstatus=ANSWER hangupdirection=B duration=0 billsec=0") in new stack
[2017-02-15 09:51:33.137] NOTICE[1505][C-00000000]: Ext. h:1 @ to-pstn: A-Number=IMSI405140603684903 A-Name= A-IMSI=IMSI405140603684903 B-Number=93278388855 B-Name= B-IMSI= hangupcause=16 dialstatus=ANSWER hangupdirection=B duration=0 billsec=0
    -- Executing [h@to-pstn:2] Hangup("SIP/00101100010-00000000", "") in new stack
  == Spawn extension (to-pstn, h, 2) exited non-zero on 'SIP/00101100010-00000000'
```

Comment: What CDR back end are you using? mine broke a while ago on a test box v.13 but I never got round to looking into why.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add `Mixmoniter` before `Dial` command it has to be hooked after answer or Progress() [refer](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_MixMonitor)

```
exten=>s,1,NoOp(testingtesting)
exten=>s,2,Dial(SIP/${ARG1},20,M(record))

[macro-record]
exten => s,1,MixMonitor(testrecording.wav)
```

Comment: It is not working.  Nothing related to Mixmonitor is appearing in logs. Not even testingtesting that I specified in NoOp.

Comment: Any call comes to your asterisk box will look for sip.conf and then matching `context` of extensions.conf. So as per you code only if call routes to `goip_context` it will come to your `macro-dialGSM`. I can't guess more since you haven't pasted full logs

Comment: I have updated the question accordingly, with new configuration and logs. Kindly check and help me :)

Comment: The problem is solved. I was doing everything rightly except adding the config at right place. :/ i was adding it to another context. Poor me :p

Comment: Glad you figured out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Monitor() with m options to record the call

exten => s,1,Monitor(wav,yourfilename,m)

exten => s,2,Dial(SIP/extension you want to dial)

and to check your recording you can simply do
exten => s,1,Playback( /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/yourfilename.wav)